# Is it ok to write comments using present participle (-ing)?

Tags: comments

After years of programming I realize I have always written my comments using present participle. For instance:

```
# Loading data sets
...
# Removing irrelevant features
...
```

Note that I use this form mainly to write a quick description of sections of my code (basically subsections).

Since I am not a native english speaker I've started wondering if this was weird or not? Should I used another form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that really shouldn't be a problem.
The comments are there to help future you and/or other people maintaining the project in the future.
As long as your time form is consistent, no one should really have a problem with your comments